# the regular expression of s/^(.*?):\s*//

Tags: regex, perl

In the following Perl example, a regular expression is used, i.e., `next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;`  But, how to understand this regular expression, `s/^(.*?):\s*//`

```
while ( <> ) {
next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
$HoA{$1} = [ split ];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It captures (and stores as `$1`) some text up to a `:`. Then it removes the captured text, the semicolon and any trailing whitespace.

Beyond the regex: if the regex succeeded in doing its job, then the code uses the captured text as a hash key whose value is an array reference. The elements of that array are the rest of the line split on whitespace.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %HoA;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  #next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
  next unless 
    s/      #s is replace match operation
      ^     #start at the beginning of the line
      (     #begin capture $1
        .*? #capture anything, but not greedy, i.e. stop before :
      )     #end capture $1
      :     #literal colon (must match)
      \s*   #optional whitespace
    //x;    #replace match with nothing, x flag allows formatting and comments
  $HoA{$1} = [ split ];
}

print Dumper(\%HoA), "\n";

__DATA__

Thingy: Thing1 Thing2
Stuff: mystuff yourstuff
other line that doesn't have a colon
```

gives

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Thingy' => [
                        'Thing1',
                        'Thing2'
                      ],
          'Stuff' => [
                       'mystuff',
                       'yourstuff'
                     ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It matches from begining of line (`^`) till a `:`, capturing whatever is in between (`(.*?)`), and any following spaces (`\s*`), and replaces it (`s/regex/replacement/`) with an empty string.

It returns a true value (the number of replacements made) if it matches, otherwise false.

For example when `$_` is `foo: bar`, it would match `foo:` and be replaced, resulting in `$_` being `bar`. After which the first capturing group `$1` will contain `foo`.

To learn more have a look at:

- [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)
- [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score -1):

They use a lot of old shortcuts which most people no longer use. Here's the code again with the missing default variable. I've also reversed the `unless` statement into a more standard format. That is, I made it an `if` statement and put the `next` as part of the `if` block:

```
while ( $_ = <> ) {
    if (not $_ =~ s/^(.*?):\s*//) {
       next;
    }
    $HoA{$1} = [ split(/\s+/, $_) ];
}
```

So, we're setting the value of `$_` from the [diamond operator](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node68.html#SECTION001011000000000000000). This basically takes the names of the files on the command line and reads each line in these files. If there are no files on the command line, it reads from STDIN.

The regular expression is trickier. The `^` anchors the regular expression to the start of the line. Otherwise a regular expression can appear anywhere in the line. For example:

```
/FOO/    #Will match "FOOBAR"  "BARFOOBAR", or "BARFOO"
/^FOO/   #Will only match "FOOBAR" and not "BARFOOBAR" or "BARFOO"
```

The `.` means any character. The `*` means zero or more of the preceding. Thus, `.*` means any number of characters (including zero characters. For example:

```
/^.*:/   #Will match any combination of characters followed by a colon (:).
```

Thus, this would match `:` on a line all by itself (zero or more), or `this is a test:`

The tricky part is the `?` which changes the meaning of the `*` in a very subtle way. Normally, regular expressions are greedy. They try to match the biggest match they can, so if you have a string:

```
my $string = "abc:def:ghij";
$string =~ /^.*:/;
```

The regular expression will match the biggest thing it can. Thus, the above would match `abc:def:` since it's the longest string that ends with a colon. By putting the `?` after the `*`, you make the regular expression as *non-greedy* -- that is it will match the smallest possible expression. Thus:

```
my $string = "abc:def:ghij";
$string =~ /^(.*):/   #Matches "abc:def:
$string =~ /^(.*?):/  #Matches "abc:"
```

The `\s` means any white space which typically means be a space or a tab character. The `*` means zero or more of those spaces. Thus, this could be no whitespace or multiple whitespaces.

```
my $string = "abc:def:  foo";
$string =~ /^(.*?):\s*/;   #Matches "abc:"
$string = "abc:   This is a test";
$string =~ /^(.*?):\s*/;   #Matches "abc:   "
```

Now, the `s` in front of the regular expression means substitution. The basic format is:

```
$string =~ s/regex/string/;
```

Where `regex` is a regular expression that matches something in `$string` while `string` is the replacement for the match. A simple example is:

```
$string = "My name is David";
$string =~ s/David/Bill/;    #String is now "My name is Bill"
```

In this case, the characters matched by the regular expression are simply replaced with nothing. That is, they're deleted from the string:

```
$string = "abc:  def";
$string =~ /^(.*?):\s*/;   #$string is now "def". "abc:   " has been removed
```

So, one more look at your code:

```
while ( $_ = <> ) {
    if (not $_ =~ s/^(.*?):\s*//) {
       next;
    }
    $HoA{$1} = [ split(/\s+/, $_) ];
}
```

This is reading from the files listed on the command line, or from STDIN, and is looking for lines that contains a colon. If the line doesn't contain a colon, it reads the next line.

If a line contains a colon, the first part of the string up to the *first* colon and any following whitespace is stripped from the string.

The `$1` refers to the part of the string that was matched inside the parentheses in the previous regular expression. That is the first part of the string up to the first colon. The `split` is splitting the remaining part of the string separated by whitespace, and making it into what is called an *anonymous list*. That is, this is creating a hash of arrays (which is why this hash is called *HoA* (Hash of Arrays).

Let's give a few examples of strings:

```
____________________________________________________
|     STRING      |           RESULTS              |
|_________________|________________________________|
| abc:  foobar    | $HoA{abc} = ["foobar"]         |
| def:bar fu      | $HoA{def} = ["bar", "fu"]      |
| ghi:jkl:mno     | $HoA{ghi} = ["jkl:mno"]        |
| ghi :  jkl: mn: | $HoA{"ghi "} = ["jkl:", "mn:"] |
|_________________|________________________________|
```

Notice that the last one will have a space at the end of the key. It's "ghi " and not "ghi".

Comment: there really is nothing old or unused about using `$_` implicitly, as long is it is in a small scope (two lines seems fine). There isn't much else it COULD mean in this case. `unless` and implicit variables are part of the language; when used appropriately they are powerful and clear-of-meaning; don't write them off so quickly. Further using `split` like this makes one just want to check out [`perldoc -f split`](http://p3rl.org/split) to see what it does!

Comment: @JoelBerger - You're right that the assumed use of `$_` in this particular case doesn't hurt readability, but it really doesn't improve it. Programming is 10% coding and 90% maintenance, and `$_` simply makes that 90% part harder which is why it's been discouraged. You don't have complete control over `$_`, so it can change without you knowing it. Conway has discouraged the use of _post-fixed_ `if` and the use of `unless` instead of `if`. However, he would probably have approved the post fixed `unless` in this particular circumstance.

Comment: @JoelBerger stated: _Further using `split` like this makes one just want to check out `perldoc -f split`._ I'm not sure that's a good thing. People should learn the ins and outs syntax and improve their skill, but having to pull out perldoc means that maintenance more difficult. The question is whether a particular coding decision makes pulling out the manual worth the effort. The use of `split` like this is rare, so it's not something someone will run into a lot. It doesn't improve the readability or efficiency. Saving typing isn't a goal. It's why I now use the _x_ flag on regex statements.